# Looking up Pandas dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have created a data frame by reading a text file. I am interested in knowing if few values exist in a particular column and if they do, I want to print the entire row.

This is my input file(analyte_map.txt):

```
Analyte_id    mass    Intensity   
A34579        101.2    786788
B12345        99.2     878787
B943470       103.89   986443
C12345        11.2      101
```

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
map_file="analyte_map.txt"
array=['A34579','B943470','D583730']
analyte_df=pd.read_table(map_file,sep="\t")
for value in array:
    if analyte_df.lookup([value],['Analyte_id']):
        print '%s\t%s'%(analyte_df['mass'],analyte_df['Intensity'])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
array=['A34579','B943470','D583730']
print (df[df.analyte_id.isin(array)])
  analyte_id    mass  Intensity
0     A34579  101.20     786788
2    B943470  103.89     986443
```

Also if need only some columns use [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

```
array=['A34579','B943470','D583730']
print (df.ix[df.analyte_id.isin(array), ['mass','Intensity']])
     mass  Intensity
0  101.20     786788
2  103.89     986443
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there a way to lookup one value at a time in a data frame and not an entire list ?

Comment: Glad can help you! Do you think `(df[df.analyte_id == 'A34579'])` ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying if df[df.analyte_id == 'A34579']: print df.Intensity

Comment: You need assign it like `df1 = df[df.analyte_id == 'A34579']` and then `print df1.Intensity`

Comment: Or better `df1 = df.ix[df.analyte_id == 'A34579', 'Intensity']`

Comment: Tried data=df[df.analyte_id == 'A34579' ] I get this error TypeError: invalid type comparison

Comment: So you need convert column analyte_id to `string` - `df1 = df[df.analyte_id.astype(str) == 'A34579']` with [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html).

Comment: That solved it, it works now. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

using `.query()` method:

```
In [9]: look_up=['A34579','B943470','D583730']

In [10]: df.query('Analyte_id in @look_up')
Out[10]:
  Analyte_id    mass  Intensity
0     A34579  101.20     786788
2    B943470  103.89     986443

In [11]: df.query('Analyte_id in @look_up')[['mass','Intensity']]
Out[11]:
     mass  Intensity
0  101.20     786788
2  103.89     986443
```